# Jailbreak detection mechanism not detecting jailbreak device

Tags: ios, swift, jailbreak, cydia

In my app I wanna detect whether the device is Jailbroken or not.  If it is jailbroken, it should not allow user to use the app. I added a function to detect but its not detecting jailbroken devices

Attaching the code for reference

*JailbrokenDetector.swift*

```
func isJailBroked() -> Bool {
    let pathsArray = ["/bin/bash", "/usr/sbin/sshd", "/etc/apt", "/private/var/lib/apt/", "/Applications/Cydia.app", "/Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib", "/Library/SBSettings/Themes/", "/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.saurik.Cydia.Startup.plist/", "/private/var/lib/cydia/private/var/mobile/Library/SBSettings/Themes/", "/var/cache/apt/", "/var/lib/cydia/", "/var/log/syslog/", "/var/tmp/cydia.log/", "/bin/bash/", "/bin/sh/", "/usr/sbin/sshd/", "/usr/bin/sshd/", "/usr/libexec/sftp-server/", "/etc/ssh/sshd_config/", "/etc/apt/", "/Applications/Cydia.app/", "/Applications/WinterBoard.app/", "/Applications/SBSettings.app/", "//private/var/lib/cydia/private/var/mobile/Library/SBSettings/Themes/", "/usr/libexec/ssh-keysign/", "/Applications/blackra1n.app", "/Applications/FakeCarrier.app", "/Applications/Icy.app", "/Applications/IntelliScreen.app", "/Applications/MxTube.app", "/Applications/RockApp.app", "/Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/LiveClock.plist", "/Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Veency.plist", "/private/var/stash", "/private/var/tmp/cydia.log", "/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.ikey.bbot.plist"]
    
    for pathString in pathsArray {
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: pathString) {
            return true
        }
    }
            
    let dummyString = “Testing”
    
    do {
        try dummyString.write(toFile:"/private/JailbreakTest.txt", atomically:true, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8)
        return true
    } catch {
        return false
    }

  if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "cydia://package/com.example.package")!) || UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "Cydia://")!) || UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "cydia://")!)) {
        return true
    }
    
    if self.canOpen(path: "/Applications/Cydia.app") ||
        self.canOpen(path: "/Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib") ||
        self.canOpen(path: "/bin/bash") ||
        self.canOpen(path: "/usr/sbin/sshd") ||
        self.canOpen(path: "/etc/apt") ||
        self.canOpen(path: "/usr/bin/ssh") {
        return true
    }
}
```

*In Appdelegate.m (Obj c)*

```
if ([JailbrokenDetector isDeviceJailBroken]) {
    exit(0);
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Where does `JailbrokenDetector` come from?  And why are you writing code in Objective-C in AppDelegate?

Comment: JailbrokenDetector is a helper class(in Swift) and project is in Obj c

Comment: Where did you get that code? What makes you think it would detect a jailbreak? Why do you want to prevent jailbroken devices in the first place?

Comment: And the answer "cannot be done reliably" is not sufficient?

Comment: Don't do this - it's a lost battle and you're wasting your time. I was in this situation, bank application, and they insisted on the Jailbreak detection. I had to do it, but it's so unreliable that I'm no longer accepting this kind of requirements from clients today. If anyone wants to use this app, they can easily force your `isJailBroked` func to return `false`. Also this `exit(0)` won't pass App Review for sure.

Comment: I Agree, though it cannot be detected completely, atleast can we detect Cydia if it is installed on the root folder

Answer (score 4):

As of iOS 14 apps cannot do these fs checks outside of its own bundle so the method you have above will not work.

Additionally, jailbreak detection is not worth it, that check can be patched to not work with just 6 lines at most, it’s a lost battle people need to stop fighting.

Comment: so what's the alternative ? leave the app to work on all devices including for those the jailbroken ones ?

Answer (score 1):

True, is not worth even trying, Jailbreak/Tweak Developers are very talented and can bypass all jailbreak detectors, I jailbreak and I have every app bypassed, I don't even understand why are you trying to stop us using your apps.